# MySQL doesn't work in terminal but can connect to database and use query

Tags: mysql, macos, command-line, terminal

I tried to use the command line to start MySQL in MacOS, but it always showed error an error:

```
~ mysql.server start
my_print_defaults: [ERROR] Found option without preceding group in config file /etc/my.cnf at line 1!
my_print_defaults: [ERROR] Fatal error in defaults handling. Program aborted!
Starting MySQL
.my_print_defaults: [ERROR] Found option without preceding group in config file /etc/my.cnf at line 1!
my_print_defaults: [ERROR] Fatal error in defaults handling. Program aborted!
my_print_defaults: [ERROR] Found option without preceding group in config file /etc/my.cnf at line 1!
my_print_defaults: [ERROR] Fatal error in defaults handling. Program aborted!
```

I searched the error and most of the answers is adding [mysqld] in my.cnf,  I checked my.cnf file, it already had [mysqld] tag.
This is my.cnf, it didn’t exist before I reinstall MySQL by [Reinstalling Mysql on Mac via Homebrew · GitHub](https://gist.github.com/lucascaton/3373792)

> Default Homebrew MySQL server config
>
> [mysqld]
>
> Only allow connections from localhost
>
> bind-address = 127.0.0.1
>
> secure_file_priv=''

Then I found another possible way is to change the character set to ANSI or ASCII, so I checked my.cnf file, but it's ASCII encoding.

```
~ enca -L none /usr/local/etc/my.cnf
7bit ASCII characters
```

I tried to stop and restart, still got the same error. BTW,  I used another command and it showed a different error:

```
~ service mysql restart
zsh: command not found: service
```

So I changed the `$PATH` config, it's still not working.

Finally I found I can start MySQL in system preferences, but the configuration file was blank, I changed it to `/usr/local/etc/my.cnf` and ran it, it shows MySQL server starting. I can use a query and connect to database.

However, I still got the same error when I used a command like above, and also I can't use data export in MySQL Workbench. I ran `/usr/local/mysql-8.0.12-macos10.13-x86_64/bin/mysqldump` , it showed the same error.

Please help.

Comment: you are probably binding only 127.0.0.1 as interface and not also localhost (they are not exactly the same thing in terms of mysql). Look for that issue and you will probably solve your issue

Comment: @LelioFaieta thanks for your reply, I searched mysql binding localhost, mysql config localhost, etc,. Most results are using 127.0.0.1, did I search the correct keyword? Then I thought just change 127.0.0.1 into localhost, still not working.

Answer (score 0):

Please ensure that your `my.cnf` file uses the `#` sign for comment lines. The error you're seeing looks like you stripped out the hash signs from some of the lines. This is what my own `my.cnf` file looks like, please note that some lines start with `#` so that they are not treated as instructions by MySQL:

```
# Default Homebrew MySQL server config
[mysqld]
# Only allow connections from localhost
bind-address = 127.0.0.1
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply, I edit the comment with #, but still got same error.

Answer (score 0):

I removed mysql and manually deleted all related files, than restart and install again, it works in terminal. However my.cnf file is not found in `/usr/local/etc/` or other places, not exists in my Mac.